# Returning a login error message using Shiro

Tags: spring-mvc, shiro

Filters and redirects are not my strong point.

I have Shiro set up and working in Spring except that I'd like to return an error message on an invalid login while staying of the same page. So I'm causing a invalid login. I've got ShiroFilterFactoryBean set with a property that should send it to /ldapLoginErr which then I map to login.jsp and then process in a error function in my Controller. But I'm getting a 404 and the url is pointing to my base url instead /ldapLoginErr or /ldapLogin.

```
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:view-controller path="/ldapLogin" view-name="ldapLogin" /> 
<mvc:view-controller path="/ldapLoginSuccess" view-name="ldapLogin" /> 
<mvc:view-controller path="/ldapLoginErr" view-name="ldapLogin" /> 


          <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/ldapLogin"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/ldapLogin"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/ldapLogin"/>
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            [urls]
            /** = ssl[8443],authc, customAuthFilter
            [main]
            /logout = logout
        </value>
    </property>   
</bean>


      @RequestMapping(value = "/ldapLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(Model model, HttpSession session){
    logger.debug("start login controller function");

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    return mav;  
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ldapLoginErr", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginErr(Model model, HttpSession session){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("errorMessage", msgSrc.getMessage("auth.notauth", null, null, null));

    return mav;  
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ldapLoginSuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginSuccess(Model model, HttpSession session){

  }


  The following didn't work either:

      <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/ldapLogin"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/ldapLoginErr"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/ldapLoginSuccess"/>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems convoluted.

Create a controller that had a GET and POST endpoint mapped to /login

GET returns the view for the login page.

POST handles the call to shiro login.

Authc filter

```
<bean id="authc" class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login"/>
</bean>
```

Filter chain def

```
<property name="filterChainDefinitions">
  <value>
    /login = authc
    /logout = logout
    /secure/** = authc
  </value>
</property>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView view() {
    return new ModelAndView(view);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, LoginForm loginForm) {
    try {
       Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
       currentUser.login(new UsernamePasswordToken(loginForm.getUsername(), loginForm.getPassword());
       WebUtils.redirectToSavedRequest(req, res, fallBackUlr);
       return null; //redirect  

    } catch(AuthenticationException e) {
       ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(view)
       mav.addObject("errorMessage", "error");
       return mav;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did have it working with controllers. It's gotten broken somehow. I have a list of realms rather than doing an explicit login as in your example. (My current problem is that shiro keeps on looping through the ldap realm if auth fails and throws and exception. Seemed to be entirely in shiro).

Comment: <bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
   <property name="realms">
         <list>
              <ref bean="authenticateLdapRealm"/>
              <ref bean="authenticateDbRolesRealm"/>
              <ref bean="DbAuthorizingRealm"/>
         </list>
     </property>
     <property name="authenticator.authenticationStrategy">
         <bean class="org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.AllSuccessfulStrategy"/>
     </property>
  </bean>

Comment: AllSuccessfulStrategy means all realms must process authenticate successfully before login is allowed. What exception is your LDAP realm throwing?

Comment: Yes. It turned out it was looping somehow because of my custom subclass to PassThruAuthenticationFilter. I haven't discovered why that's a problem but when I just use PassThruAuthenticationFilter it doesn't loop on failed ldap login.

Comment: So as suggested justed added a POST.  @RequestMapping(value = "/ldapLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loginErr(Model model, HttpSession session){
     
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
  mav.addObject("errorMessage", msgSrc.getMessage("auth.notauth.signon", null, null, null));
  mav.setViewName("ldapLogin");
    
     return mav;  
    }

Comment: why not edit your question with your current config. i'll look at that and see if I can spot the issue.

Comment: there's no longer any issue

Answer (score 7):

When authentication fails, Shiro redirects to the login page and sets a request attribute named `shiroLoginFailure`.  So in my login.jsp page I added the following:

```
<c:if test="${shiroLoginFailure != null}">
    Username or password incorrect
</c:if>
```

If you are not using JSTL and EL, you can use JSP scriptlets:

```
<%
  if (request.getAttribute("shiroLoginFailure")!=null) {
%>
Username or password incorrect
<%
  }
%>
```